# How do I get pixel by pixel depth data out of a .exr file?

Tags: file-format, .exr, luxrender-render-engine

I have been trying to get pixel by pixel depth data out of a .exr file.  I am using blender and rendering with Lux Render.  I need to get pixel by pixel depth data, and have read that if I use the z-buffer in blender and render, then save it as a .exr file from Lux Render, there should be pixel by pixel depth data in the .exr file.  However, I have not been able to read the .exr.  I have access to Matlab.  Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Lux render.

Comment: @someonewithpc luxrender is also an add-on. It will allow you to use luxrender as render engine in blender... I think it on-topic...

Comment: Yes, external renderers with Blender integration are ON topic. http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/672/are-questions-about-external-render-engines-on-topic

Answer (score 5):

Enable the Z buffer on the output settings:

[image]

To check if the Z buffer is correctly rendered, you can load the OpenEXR file in the compositor and add a normalize node to visualize the Z-channel:

[image]